# Android, Tabs without Actionbar

Tags: android, android-tabs

This question has been asked (for example, here [Using ViewPager with Tabs without actionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410704/using-viewpager-with-tabs-without-actionbar)), however the answer there doesn't work. There's some links to [Swipey](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html) but unfortunately the link is broken too.

The example from Android site [EffectiveNavigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) uses Actionbar to host the tab fragment, so obviously if I set a .NoActionBar theme, then there's no host. Any different way? Thanks.

**Update** screenshot of what I want to create, at the top, there's no actionbar.
[image]

**Update 2** this is from the google example, there's an actionbar on top (titled "Effective navigation), which I want to get rid of

[image]

Comment: So where exactly will the tabs go if not in an Action Bar?

Comment: It's at the top, see my update.

Comment: Those are Action Bar tabs.

Comment: @Squonk pls see my 2nd update.

Comment: If you get rid of the icon and the title string then the tabs should fit the top in place of them. Your only other alternative is to use a `TabHost`

Comment: awesome, can you answer, so I can mark. Tks

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solution of your problem is already given in http://developer.android.com/

**To disableAction-bar Icon and Title, you must do two things:**

```
 setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
 setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hides action bar title
```

Follow The Steps given in [Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)

Write Following Code in **`OnCreate()`**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hides action bar title
        //rest of your code...
}
```

[image]

**After Android updated Actionbar to Toolbar there are many changes in Actionbar Tabs.**

> Please follow below links to create swipable tabs in Andoid.

**Design Structure :**

[Tabs Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-types-of-tabs)

[image]

Some of the very useful links are below. Please refer to them.

**Download sample zip from below link**

http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

**Or Refer these links**

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

This may help you...

Comment: I am trying to use that but it gives me an error... any ideas?

Comment: @Vlad : Hi Vlad, this is an old answer. Android got updated in way to far from this so you have to use new methods and fundamentals to implement this type of view. Actionbar got updated to Toolbar. 

Please follow below link to implement this type of behavior.
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Comment: I just want to say well done for a pretty exemplary answer

Answer (score 9):

You can:

- Use a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip`
- Use a `ViewPager` with the `TabPageIndicator` class from the ViewPagerIndicator library
- Use a `ViewPager` with other third-party tab indicators (e.g., in [the "View Pagers" category at the Android Arsenal](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/111))
- Use a `ViewPager` and design your own tabbed indicator
- Use a `FragmentTabHost` and skip the swiping part

Answer (score 0):

Along with

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Use this as well

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```